# Downloading 40K file after every 200 download all the 200 files should move to a new directory by creating one

Tags: shell

Using `wget` im downloading 40k files with `.deb` extention,

After every 200 download of .deb files i want to create a new_directory and move those 200 files to that `new_directory`,

And so on for rest of the files

Please help me!!

Comment: What do you want to know? Do you miss the commands or are not able to count the downloads?

Comment: i have command to download files, i want a logic where after every 200 download it should create a directory and move to a new_directory,
currently i have a logic where after 40K files downloaded it is moving 200files to new_directory, i dont have enough space on my system to download it onto the same directory

Answer (score 0):

An example on how to do something every `nth` time in a shell script:

```
for i in {1..20}; do
  if [ $(($i % 2)) -eq 0 ]; then
    echo $i
  fi
done
```

This prints:

```
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20
```

I expect you to download your files in a loop. If so, you may take the loop counter and `mod`it by the desired amount (in your case 200).